# in snowflake, how to get a list of all values of a certain key out a list of key values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, key-value

Have a column of a large semi structured object, one of the parts is a key value on its own (actually a list of key values) I can get it like so:

```
t.payload:questions_and_answers
```

which gives:

```
[{"answer":"yes","position":0,"question":"would you"}, 
{"answer":"because","position":1,"question":"what"}]
```

I want to get from that:

```
yes, because
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FLATTEN:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t
AS
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{questions_and_answers:[{"answer":"yes","position":0,"question":"would you"}, 
{"answer":"because","position":1,"question":"what"}]}') AS payload;
```

Query:

```
SELECT s.value:answer::STRING
FROM t
,TABLE(FLATTEN (input => t.payload, PATH =>'questions_and_answers')) s;
```

Or if single output is required:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(s.value:answer::STRING, ', ') AS result
FROM t
,TABLE(FLATTEN (input => t.payload, PATH =>'questions_and_answers')) s;
```

Output:

[image]